# Direct download git without installer

Tags: macos, git, installation, download

How might I be able to download git (console or UI, I don't care which) without using the installer (direct download) on mac. Maybe there is a possibility of having an app on the desktop that I can launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) :

```
brew install git
```

Or compiling from source (as described at [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)) :

```
// get tar via curl, wget.. then :

tar -zxf git-1.7.2.2.tar.gz
cd git-1.7.2.2
make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

Comment: Although I had just derped and my question was obsolete, I accepted your answer. If git wasn't already installed I would've been able to compile it form the source.

Answer (score 1):

Can also try [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/):

```
port install git
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that git was already installed on my mac, but the previous two answers were good as well.

Comment: I have upvoted the other two answers to give credit.

Comment: Thank you for the credit!  Might I suggest, though, that you accept one of the two answers (meriadec's, probably, since it's more complete), in case someone else wanders into this question wanting to install some other version of `git` on their Mac (e.g. to keep it more up-to-date)?

Comment: Also another thing you can do is go to http://mac.github.com/ and get the graphic interface (it directly downloads the app, instead of using an installer).